# How to carry out EDA on data consisting of 2D variables

Tags: time-series, clustering, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a temporal dataset that consists of 2D variables (angle, length)

I want to investigate:

1. whether the data has any noticeable structure (e.g. clusters)
2. Whether the sequence of variables (a time series) follow a noticeable pattern that can be modelled/predicted.

Comment: So, plot angle and length as a scatter plot. Then join them in time order. Then plot both against time. If your angle flips around $0^\circ \equiv 360^\circ$ more care may be needed. How does length behave? Presumably it is always positive, but is it highly skewed?

Comment: @NickCox Thanks, I think you're unto something here ... Could you elaborate more and submit this as an answer? I don't understand parts of your comments (shown in bold):  1. plot angle and length as a scatter plot - **Then join them in time order.** (please clarify this statement)  2. **Then plot both against time.** (not sure how to show 3 variables on a 2D graph ... please clarify). Last but not  least, length is a positive real number.

Comment: length is a positive real number, and angle <= 2pi (radians)

Comment: Join the points on a scatter plot, first observation in time to second, second to third, and so forth. A plot of angle and length against time may need separate panels, given the different scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Plot angle and length as a scatter plot. Length is evidently positive, which allows (e.g.) square root or logarithmic scale for length if length is highly skewed in distribution.
2. Join the points on the scatter plot in time order,  first observation in time to second, second to third, and so on, to show a trajectory in state space.
3. Plot both against time. That may need separate panels, given the different scales.
4. Sometimes the mapping from angle to (sine, cosine) helps as sine and cosine have different interpretations.

With all plots, if your angle flips around $0^\circ \equiv 360^\circ$, more care may be needed. For example, if angle is really compass direction, or time of day, or date in year, flips past North, midnight, or end of year are quite likely. If angle is say some kind of deflection, it may be close to zero most frequently and this won't bite. Sine and cosine parameterisation ensures smoother plots as sine and cosine vary smoothly around zero angle, and indeed everywhere.